# create a div that overlays on an html file?

Tags: php

I have a code (html) and I want it to be a div that overlays on another html file. 
I want the div to appear when the user submits his message so it confirms that his message has been successfully sent.

as a conclusion, I want a html file to overlay on another one, so it appears as a form validation in php echo. So it has to be as a popup window validating the user's actions.
How to do it?

Thanks in advance. any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: I recommend having a look at jQuery Dialog - easy way to create customizable overlays etc

Comment: For the most simple solution, use javascript's `alert('your message')` or `confirm('Choose an action')`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is not meant by PHP, it is meant by Javascript or Jquery. What you want here is called modal. To see some implementation for modal you may checkout Jqueryui from [this link](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation)

Comment: I don't know how to insert jQuery in html and customize it. Can you tell me how?

Comment: The linked page regarded in the answer, contains a detailed example. Just you have to click on `View Source` on that page.